# I am struggling to discover a good method to link my server to my Roblox game

Tags: json, server, lua, roblox

Yesterday I set up an Ubuntu server to run some out of game scripts to work in conjunction with in game scripts. I enabled HTML calls as well as Third Party access in my game editor. I have also looked through the object browser for possible objects to use in the get and post requests. I have come up with some code, but it is completely nonfunctional.

```
local UserId = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mining = UrlEncode("http://216.128.0.0:34648/")

for mining in Connect(function() 
        
            
            
        
    getAsync(mining.."/"..UserId)
    PostAsync(mining.."/"..UserId)
    end)
    
     do JSONEncode()
    
    JSONDecode()
    
Any advice or help would be appreciated. Thanks.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML calls"?

Comment: Calls to the server is what I am referring to. In the Roblox Studio it is called http requests.

Comment: If that is your real IP, I suggest you edit the question to a hypothetical one. On that note, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you just sending the UserID to the server?

Comment: I edited the IP to a null one. I want to set up an offline afk reward system using my cloud server and need to sync with that because I will have in game purchases that can come out of it, and rewards that can go in. If that makes sense.

Comment: If you're trying to make an afk reward system, you could also use [DataStoreService](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/DataStoreService) as a persistence layer. When the Player leaves, serialize the server date and time into a key attached to the Player, and when they come back, compare that against the current server date and time.

Comment: I appreciate the idea, but the reward system is multi platform, where roblox is only one of the different systems being integrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First, enable HTTP if you haven't already:**
[image]

iirc, you cannot send http requests from the client: you'll have to use a server script. This means that you cannot get the player via `LocalPlayer`. I've provided an example of a [POST request](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/HttpService/PostAsync) which uses JSON to send data.

*Script in **ServerScriptService:***

```lua
local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")
local serverURL = "http://216.128.0.0:34648/mining"

function mine(player)
    local arguments = {
        ["userID"] = player.UserId,
        ["name"] = player.Name
    }
    
    local response = HttpService:PostAsync(serverURL, HttpService:JSONEncode(arguments), Enum.HttpContentType.ApplicationJson)
    local responseData = HttpService:JSONDecode(response) --assuming the response is in JSON
    print(responseData)
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(mine)
```

I don't know how your server is structured so you may have to work around this. There's a wonderful [wiki page](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/HttpService#:%7E:text=Destroying%20(%20)-,Code%20Samples,-Astronauts%20in%20Space) that has more information and examples.